# How to pass multiple parallel streams to Junit5 Parameterized test?

Tags: java, junit, junit5, parameterized-tests

I have two ArrayList<> Objects of equal lengths, and my Junit5 parameterized test has the syntax:

```
@ParamterizedTest
@MethodSource("dummyfunction");
void functionName(String s1, String s2)
{
.....
.....
}


private Stream<Arguments> dummyfunction()
{
     ArrayList<String> arr1;
     ArrayList<String> arr2;
     .....
     .....
    return something;
}
```

How can I return the elements from each ArrayList so that one list provides *s1* and the other provide *s2* as per the *functionName* function?

Comment: Are `arr1` and `arr2` of equal length and you want all pairs, i.e. `(arr1.get(0), arr2.get(0)), (arr1.get(1), arr2.get(1)), ...` or do you want all permutations of elements in both lists?

Comment: all pairs, as you mentioned, and not the permutations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Naiv solution that prints

```
s1 = [1], s2 = [a]
s1 = [2], s2 = [b]
s1 = [3], s2 = [c]
```

with the following implementation

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("dummyFunction")
void functionName(String s1, String s2) {
    System.out.println("s1 = [" + s1 + "], s2 = [" + s2 + "]");
}

static Stream<Arguments> dummyFunction() {
    List<String> list1 = List.of("1", "2", "3");
    List<String> list2 = List.of("a", "b", "c");

    Assertions.assertEquals(list1.size(), list2.size());

    List<Arguments> arguments = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
        arguments.add(Arguments.of(list1.get(i), list2.get(i)));
    }

    return arguments.stream();
}
```